# How to receive info from android broadcast <receiver>

Tags: android, tracking, receiver, mobile-app-tracker

I am new to android application tracking, I want to create a page where i can see who has installed app from my reference 
I will be using broadcast receiver in my android menifest 
 broadcast receiver

```
<receiver android:name="com.myeapptracker.Tracker" android:exported="true">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and i will be sharing link to download app like this
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hellochatty&referrer=tracking_id%3C123456

I just want to know what code should I write to receive details from android broadcast.

I am basically .NET & PHP programmer, guide me what language or method should i use to receive the info from android broadcast as i mentioned code above.

I know the topic is very broad, but i just want a little hint, like what and  method/language to use.